# Start mongodb unsharded cluster with replics sets on localhost

Tags: mongodb, replication, database-replication, sharding, replicaset

I am trying to start a MongoDB cluster with at least one replica set on `localhost`. For simplicity, an unsharded cluster is fine. I am following this documentation [Deploy a Replica Set for Testing and Development](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set-for-testing/)

This documentation is a bit confusing to me. is there a simple straight forward way?

Answer (score 0):

Here I am creating a mongo cluster (unsharded) with `1 PRIMARY node` and `2 SECONDARY nodes` (replica). PRIMARY node runs on default port 27017 and other 2 replica node on port 27018 and 27019.

First, create a DB path for all 3 instances. For me, its `/data/db/27017` for PRIMARY and `/data/db/27018` and `/data/db/27019` for replica. make sure you have to write access to these directories.

Now follow the below steps ...

```
1- start 3 mongo instances
./mongod --port 27017 --dbpath /data/db/27017 --replSet rs0 &
./mongod --port 27018 --dbpath /data/db/27018 --replSet rs0 &
./mongod --port 27019 --dbpath /data/db/27019 --replSet rs0 &


2- login to mongo cli with PRIMARY port and initiate replicas 
./mongo 127.0.0.1:27017/test      //cli
rs.initiate()                     // replica set init
rs.conf()                         // replica set config
rs.status()                       // replica set status
rs.add("localhost:27018")         //Add members to Replica Set
rs.add("localhost:27019")         //Add members to Replica Set


3- check cluster info
db.isMaster()
rs.slaveOk()     // to perform cli commands on replica
```